# Skipping an argument in an sprintf format string in R

Tags: r, printf

I have a function that returns the string representation of a period given two dates, but I want the user to be able to control the format. For this I'm using `sprintf` and the caller passes in the format string, giving the caller flexibility to use things like:

```
> sprintf("from %s - %s","Mon 21","Sun 27")
[1] "from Mon 21 - Sun 27"
```

or

```
> sprintf("%s - %s inclusive","Mon 21","Sun 27")
[1] "Mon 21 - Sun 27 inclusive"
```

I've discovered that if you don't have enough % marks in the format string it doesn't matter, so you can do:

```
> sprintf("week begin %s","Mon 21","Sun 27")
[1] "week begin Mon 21"
```

but I can't find a way to construct a format string that drops the first argument and returns "week ending Sun 27". Note I really want a solution that only changes the format string, or to know if this is impossible...

I've tried tricks like making the first format 0-width with `%0s` but no joy:

```
> sprintf("%0s week ending %s","Mon 21","Sun 27")
[1] "Mon 21 week ending Sun 27"
```

Obviously I can make this work by making the caller say whether the format uses the start and/or end dates but if there was a way to do it with a `sprintf` format string that would be neat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this one?

```
> sprintf("week ending %2$s","Mon 21","Sun 27")
[1] "week ending Sun 27"
```

Another example (to expand the subject),

```
> sprintf("week ending either %2$s or %4$s", "Mon 21","Sun 27","Mon 28","Sun 2")
[1] "week ending either Sun 27 or Sun 2"
```

Comment: Yes that works. I don't see any mention of that in the sprintf man page so it must be an R extension to the standard.